# I would like to better understand how Grakn is handling super nodes?

Tags: vaticle-typedb

1. Is it just sharding and sending multiple queries?
2. If it is the case how it keeps the relations over shards?
3. Can I set or hint the sharding method?
4. Can I split the dataset and somehow hint there is another dataset in which a "cloned" entity resides?

Answer (score 0):

Grakn handles super node sharding transparently in the schema, and will have automatic instance sharding in upcoming versions.

Sharding is a relatively simple mechanism, in which a node with more than a number of edges (set by `knowledge-base.type-shard-threshold` in the `grakn.properties`) will be split into a root node, with new edges attaching to child nodes that are invisible so the user. Since the goal of this is to be hands-off, we don't currently offer a way to control the sharding mechanism.

That should cover questions 1-3, but I don't follow question 4. Splitting a dataset but inserting it into the same keyspace will be no different from not splitting it in the first place. Splitting it into two keyspaces will isolate your data and there will be no sharing at all.

Comment: Thank you.
About question 4 - The idea was to split the data between two datasets (key spaces). One with personal data and one with other data yet have a single person entity. Then expolit the sharding mechanism to split the queries between the datasets. This should allow give the two datasets different permissions and have different results depending on the querying use permissions. Another benefit was to allow putting a specific dataset with parts of the data in-memory while keeping others on disk.

Comment: Splitting between keyspaces sounds sensible for security and data partitioning for sure. Grakn doesn't currently let you specify in-memory only, as everything is persisted to cassandra. But I hope you succeed with your project and if you have any small questions join our slack at https://grakn.ai/slack !